# How I can fix element

Tags: html, css, web

How I can fix my count text on div block?  There is a problem when you change the screen size.

**Normal**

[image]

**On screen resize**

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
span.right-corner{
  position: relative;  
  float: left; 
  left: 250px;  
  bottom: 25px;  
  width: auto;  
}
div.top-block{
  position: relative; 
  float: left; 
  left: 240px;
  bottom: 40px; 
  width: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="top-block">
    <div class="huge"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <span class="badge right-corner">${count}</span>
    <h4>Архів</h4>
    <a class="watcher" href="/edocs/main/archive/${offnoteType}"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question and the code is not clear. What you are trying to do exactly ?

Comment: What is ur expected output..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next time please paste a working code to be easier for us to try help you.

[Check this solution](http://codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/EyxePZ)

Instead of use float ( which i don't recommend... just for a few particular case ) 
I think with position relative and absolute is easier for your case.

Resize and see, the "notifications" block is always in the corner top, right of his container.

- parent `position: relative`
- absolute child container: `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;`

Now you just have to play with padding to achieve a good design.

Tip: gonna be better for you if use semantic html instead of 1048105715 divs ;)